# DetalView get_context_data into ListView

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a bit of a long question. I am writing a bookkeeping system in django

I have a model for supplier as follows

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    supplier_number = models.IntegerField()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.supplier_name
```

and also the expense model as

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    invoice_date   = models.DateField()
    supplier_name  = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='expenses')
    description    = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def amt_excl_vat(self):
        if self.supplier_name.intra_community is None:
            vat_amount = (Decimal(self.expense_vat.vat_rate)/100)/(1+(Decimal(self.expense_vat.vat_rate)/100))*self.amt_incl_vat
            amt_excl_vat = self.amt_incl_vat - vat_amount
        else:
            vat_amount = 0
            amt_excl_vat = self.amt_incl_vat - vat_amount
        return amt_excl_vat
```

in my `SupplierDetailView(DetailView)` I calculated some values in def `get_context_data` like

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs["pk"]

        supplier = get_object_or_404(Supplier, pk=pk)
        expenses = supplier.expenses.all()

        expenditure_ex = 0
        for item in expenses:
            expenditure_ex += item.amt_excl_vat()

        context['expenditure_ex'] = expenditure_ex
        return context
```

the results give me correct values. I want to get the value of `expenditure_ex` in the `SupplierListView(ListView)`

sorry for a long question

TIA

Comment: Move the logic to the model, not the view.

Comment: the Supplier or Expense model?